# How do I build a dict using list comprehension?

Tags: python

How do I build a dict using list comprehension?

I have two lists.

```
 series = [1,2,3,4,5]
 categories = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','B']
```

I want to build a dict where the categories are the keys.

Thanks for your answers I'm looking to produce:

```
 {'A' : [1, 3], 'B' : [2, 5], 'C' : [4]}
```

Because the keys can't exist twice

Comment: What is the output you want to have? `{'A' : [1, 3], 'B' : [2, 5], 'C' : [4]}`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to have a list of tuples. The tuples are key/value pairs. You don't need a comprehension in this case, just zip:

```
dict(zip(categories, series))
```

Produces `{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 4}` (as pointed out by comments)

Edit: After looking at the keys, note that you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary. So without further clarifying what you want, I'm not sure what solution you're looking for.

Edit: To get what you want, it's probably easiest to just do a for loop with either setdefault or a defaultdict.

```
categoriesMap = {}
for k, v in zip(categories, series):
    categoriesMap.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

That should produce `{'A': [1, 3], 'B': [2, 5], 'C': [3]}`

Comment: This will produce "{'A': 3, 'C': 4, 'B': 5}", and I'm not sure that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks Kris although my result dict only has 3 items in it.

Comment: You should use `defaultdict` instead of a standard dict with `setdefault`. ie `map = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: You are overwriting `map()`, just use different name for your dictionary.

Comment: @Voo I know. Someone else already provided the default dict solution below, I though I'd show another way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

```
from collectons import defaultdict

series = [1,2,3,4,5]
categories = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','B']

result = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in zip(categories, series)
    result[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than being clever (I have an itertools solution I'm fond of) there's nothing wrong with a good, old-fashioned for loop:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> series = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> categories = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C','B']
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for c,s in zip(categories, series):
...     d[c].append(s)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [1, 3], 'C': [4], 'B': [2, 5]})
```

This doesn't use a list comprehension because a list comprehension is the wrong way to do it.  But since you seem to really want one for some reason: how about:

```
>> dict([(c0, [s for (c,s) in zip(categories, series) if c == c0]) for c0 in categories])
{'A': [1, 3], 'C': [4], 'B': [2, 5]}
```

That has not one but *two* list comprehensions, and is very inefficient to boot.

Comment: This is the best answer but doesn't use list comprehension

Comment: `{c0: [s for c, s in zip(categories, series) if c == c0] for i, c0 in enumerate(categories) if c0 not in categories[i+1:]}`, the inside loop is still list comprehension, btw. :\

Answer (score 1):

In principle you can do as Kris suggested: `dict(zip(categories, series))`, just be aware that  there can not be duplicates in `categories` (as in your sample code).

**EDIT :**

Now that you've clarified what you intended, this will work as expected:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(categories, series):
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={ k:[] for k in categories }
map(lambda k,v: d[k].append(v), categories, series )
```

result:

```
d is now = {'A': [1, 3], 'C': [4], 'B': [2, 5]}
```

or (equivalent) using setdefault (thanks Kris R.)

```
d={}
map(lambda k,v: d.setdefault(k,[]).append(v), categories, series )
```

Comment: this will produce {'A': 3, 'C': 4, 'B': 5} I'm after {'A' : [1, 3], 'B' : [2, 5], 'C' : [4]}